# How To Take Crumbs/Dust Off My Desk

Tags: cleaning

Sometimes I have dust, crumbs, pieces of paper, etc... on my desk. I tried taking them off with my hand but they just stayed there. I have an IKEA wooden desk. Do you have any idea how I could clean it?

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing crumbs that can't be wiped away with your hand. A photo would probably help. You may want to amend your question to describe why taking them off with your hand doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try a vacuum cleaner or brush?

Answer (score 2):

Place a damp (not wet) wash-cloth, dust-cloth, clean rag, or sponge between your bare unembellished hand and your IKEA wooden desk when you next try removing dust, crumbs, pieces of paper, etc… off your IKEA wooden desk.

Repeat as necessary.

This modification to your procedure should improve your performance.

Good luck. Please let us know about your progress.

Comment: Love it! This is solid advice but still sounds very tongue-in-cheek.